# Image with transparency over video

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, libvlc

Im using C# in VS2017 and have a Vlc Control to play a video.

I want to overlap some part of the video with a PNG image with transparency. In VS2017, elements are transparent to their parent. So, to make the image be transparent to the video I have to set it as child of the video.

But if I do that, the image doesn't display at all. Video is always refreshing and overlapping the image (even if I do a constant `BringToFront` in the image).

So, I change the Parent of the image to the form. Now the image displays, but through it's transparency I see the form's background, not the video.

Target platform is Windows. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Could you share a small reproducing project? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My honest opinion:  You need to use a XAML wrapper so that you can write XAML in your WinForms app, or if you have the option, just make the whole app in WPF and XAML.  Things like this are done easily in XAML and will have much better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem with windows forms. I believe there is no simple solution where you can use another control (e.g a picturebox) and make it transparent such that you can see the video behind it.

One thing you can do is to create another form, set it as topMost, set it's MDiParent to the form containing the VLC control and set its FormBorderStyle to None. Then set it's background to be the image you want to overlay and set it's opacity property to say 50%. This should give you the effect you want but it is a bit of a work around.

If you can you should move to WPF as your UI technology which should solve this and allow you to overlay a picture box with a transparency that doesn't just show the background of the main form behind it and actually shows the video.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how you're using libvlc.

Do you have to blend the image with the control itself? Shouldn't you blend any given image with the video frames?

If so, try using **--alphamask-mask** filter:

> ```
>    --alphamask-mask=<string>
>      Transparency mask
>      Alpha blending transparency mask. Uses a png alpha channel.
> ```

If you're using libvlc.net you can do this by adding an option:

```
vlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption(<options>);
```

Comment: Im creating a vlcControl in design, and assigning a video and playing it through code.

Comment: I don't have to blend the image and video. I have to play a video full screen in the background and OVERLAP an image with transparency on it.

Comment: Winforms or WPF?

Comment: This are my references, I think is Winforms:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;